# Importing working eclipse project to new version

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I had eclipse Helios installed, however, due to Licence Violation I wasn't able to install plugins. I uninstalled Java SDK 1.7, deleted the Eclipse folder, and downloaded eclipse JUNO (should be the latest Version). I've installed Android sdk on Windows, however, it Looks like Eclipse just installed it a second time in a different Directory after importing it.

My issue is, that I am importing an existing Project, (new other.. build Android Project from source) and there are no compilation errors. As soon as I run the program I get this ErrorLog:

```
12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxxname.xnamepre.xnamepre2012/xxxxname.xnamepre.xnamepre2012.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Space

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Space

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at xxxxname.xnamepre.xnamepre2012.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:30)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  ... 11 more

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
android.support.v7.widget.Space

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)

12-14 00:06:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  ... 21 more
```

On line SplashScreen.java:30 stands `setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);` I haven't touched the files. In the `res/layout` Folder is the splashscreen.xml file.

Also, how can I add the mini icon for virtual Android Device Manager back to my toolbar?

Comment: Edit: i fixed this issue: i was using android.support.v7.widget.Space widgets in all XML files. I have no clue, why they cannot be used anymore, i think eclipse added them for compatibility issues... wouldnt surprise me if it crashes on other androids now.. (intended was 2.2++(sdk8) and it has build target sdk15. I Change my question now to - does the delete of These lines effect my code? I couldnt notice any difference in the Emulator and i'm absolutely sure that i have not added These widgets.

Answer (score 0):

The android sdk only supports jdk 1.6 currently. Also, You can find instructions on installing the adt plugin for eclipse here: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html